# Can my laboratory rat be ill?

Tags: health, rat

Picture below shows Maya, my lab rat, my friend.
[image]

But something must happen. She seems to be rather sad, have bad coordination and appears to be somehow weakened. She refusing her favorite food and losing weight. Do someone knows what it can be and how to cure whatever it is ? I know it is not much informations i giving you but it is all what i know. Please.
*Animal abuse note : Small cage she is in is used only for sleeping. She is with me every time I have time for her.*

Comment: you need to take your rat to a vet,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your laboratory rat can be ill.

And there is a very good change that the illness is a [form of cancer](https://science.howstuffworks.com/innovation/scientific-experiments/lab-rats-cancer.htm). Being a laboratory rat does not mean a clean rat, it means they were bred for a purpose. And became friendly pets in the process.

**To know what is happening to your rat, please take her / him to the vet.**